# Can I get the MAC address of a SQL Server connection?

Tags: sql-server, connection

I know I can get the IPAddress and ConnectionID of a SQL Server connection with this query:

> select client_net_address, connection_id from sys.dm_exec_connections
>   where session_id = @@spid

But is there a way to get the corresponding MAC address?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know that the client _has_ a [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_Address) and that it is only a single hop away on the same IP subnet then you might be able to obtain it from the ARP cache. Not every device has a MAC address, nor are they guaranteed to be globally unique.

Answer (score 4):

See Below:

```
select net_address from sysprocesses where spid = @@SPID
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that but it gave a value that does not seem to be the MAC Address of either the client machine or the server.

Comment: You just need to format it correctly: 

select MAC=substring(net_address,1,2)+'-'+substring(net_address,3,2)+'-'+substring(net_address,5,2)+'-'+substring(net_address,7,2)+'-'+substring(net_address,9,2)+'-'+substring(net_address,11,2)
from sysprocesses
where spid = @@SPID

Comment: Nope, it's definitly not a MAC address. I also compared it with "ifconfig /all" and there's no such ids.

Answer (score 2):

The following section is sql command to get the server's MAC address of the network it currently using:

```
declare @t table (i uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(),  m as cast(i as char(36)))
insert into @t default values;
select substring(m,25,2) + '-' + substring(m,27,2) + '-' + substring(m,29,2) + '-' + substring(m,31,2) + '-' + substring(m,33,2) + '-' +  substring(m,35,2) AS MacAddress FROM @t
select * from @t
```

Notice that if you have more than 1 NIC, this result will show you only one.

Comment: Shai, this is a code dump. Put some words to it. Show us your swag.

Comment: To me is OK: I get the same MACaddress of IPConfig/ALL

Answer (score 1):

```
    declare @t table
    (
    i uniqueidentifier default newsequentialid(),
    m as cast(i as char(36))
    )

    insert into @t default values;

    select
        substring(m,25,2) + '-' + 
        substring(m,27,2) + '-' + 
        substring(m,29,2) + '-' +
        substring(m,31,2) + '-' +
        substring(m,33,2) + '-' +
        substring(m,35,2) AS MacAddress
    FROM @t

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCurrentIP] ()
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IP_Address varchar(255);

    SELECT @IP_Address = client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;

    Return @IP_Address;
END
```

this code is from [1]:http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/323721/How-to-get-Client-IP-Address-in-SQL-Server

Comment: This is brilliant, and for the life of me I cannot understand how it works. However it appears to be giving the MAC Address of the server, not the connected client.

Comment: @NeilW `NewSequentialGuid` ensures the uniqueness part by setting the last 12 characters to be the (first) MAC address of the SQL server.

Comment: Code to get Server's Mac Address was given to me by one of the colleague, and i asked him the same question, he did explain to me something but I cant remember what explanation he gave to me. Will ask him again on Monday when i see him :)

Comment: and one more thing there is a warning with this code NewSequentialGuid() might give unexpected results if VMWare on the server.